# Why is vortex.data.microsoft.com using my CSP?

Tags: security, websocket, content-security-policy

I have a webapp that uses a custom web protocol `my-webpcl://` to launch a local application. Essentially, an .exe launched from an HTML page, same method used by the Valve with the Steam `steam://` Browser Protocol.

The application, after authenticating that the launch request is valid, initializes a single connection websocket server on the local host that the webpage connects to.

The following CSP is on the html page to allow connections to the local websocket server as well as to allow the custom web protocol. (This is the only place it appears, and the only file on the content delivery platform's server containing it.)

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src 'self' ws://localhost:12011 ws://127.0.0.1:12011; object-src 'self' my-webpcl:;">`

The above works perfectly as intended. Recently however, our data tech noticed that his browsers console was spitting out the following error when doing other things on the platform:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://vortex.data.microsoft.com/collect/v1'
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
"connect-src 'self' ws://localhost:12011 ws://127.0.0.1:12011".
- Sender.ts:421
```

What stood out to me immediately was that this error contained my CSP declaration. Not entirely, but up to the end of the first semicolon.

Sender.ts is not our code, we don't use or connect to that vortex URL, and when inspected the calling file spits back `Could not load content for https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/JavaScript/JavaScriptSDK/Sender.ts (HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE)`

The weird part is the data tech didn't even access the one page that contained that CSP, and it happens repeatedly when you access a page that queries the server side database.

While we host the server that the content delivery platform runs on. The platform itself is a large 3rd party solution to which we have little insight. (Asking their support the same question, but don't expect a timely response that isn't "That's not us, ask your local network admin.")

I don't even know the question to ask really, as I'm just left wondering:

1. WTF is vortex.data.microsoft.com, and why is it being connected to using a CSP from another page?
2. *Is it a leak, hole, or other security issue we need to be concerned with?*
3. Why/How is the CSP being scraped from a file that was part of a zip upload, and hasn't been accessed by the client at the time o the error?